# sticky footer with height set on containing element

Tags: html, css

I am able to set sticky footer on web pages following instructions

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

It suggests `min-height:100%`and height not being set

```
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
```

However, in one of the page I need to set `height:100% in`.page-wrap to adjust height of its children. After I set height:100%, my sticky footer does not work and appears in the middle of page.

Is there a way to make sticky footer work with the height set to 100% in .page-wrap??

Comment: Are you going to show us your fiddle?

Comment: I use jQuery to make sticky footer.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov...thats what I am thinking to do. anyways for what was asked before here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/263/  ......if you remove height statement from container-fluid....then it works

Comment: @Itay...I have included the fiddle...please see my comment above as well

Answer (score 1):

Remove `height:100%` element from `container-fluid` class

```
.container-fluid {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100%;
 /*height: 100%;*/ /*Remove the height and it will work fine*/
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/qT8vV/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
   .container-fluid 
   {
    position:relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid green;
   }
```

This will put the footer to the bottom of the page. This will work fine.